# Tableau Formatting Numbers in calculated field

Tags: tableau-api

I have a calculate field named Table Measure, and it contains Percent and Numbers.  How can I format the % with 1 decimal place and the number of records with comma and zero decimal place? I tried to use `FORMAT([% of Composite VOC]),"#.0%")` it gave me an error.

```
    IF [Toggle] = 1 THEN ([% of Sale 1]) ELSEIF [Toggle] = 2 THEN [Total of
 Profit] ELSEIF [Toggle] = 3 THEN [% of Discount] ELSEIF [Toggle] = 4 THEN % of
 Commission ] ELSEIF [Toggle] = 5 THEN [Number of Records] END) END
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: are you using R or Python for format function?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the calculation "Table Measure" -> Select "Default Properties" -> "Number Format" -> "Percentage"...update to 1 decimal.

Comment: I need to format it in the Calculated field. So when the parameter is switch to a percentage measure the mark label will be formatted in %.

Comment: @Arsee Why not create two separate calculated fields: one with %s and one with numbers? That would make this a lot easier.

Comment: The values are already calculated but the issue was it is not in % format.  There are 4 measures 3 of them are % 1 in whole numbers. I was following this https://mixpixviz.blogspot.com/2016/01/using-parameter-to-change-table.html#!/2016/01/using-parameter-to-change-table.html